# Difference between types of build configration ?? and how can I make an app variant in android studio ??

Tags: android, android-studio, build, module, configuration

I am relatively new to android app development. I've been studying from android developer site. But I can't get my head around different configurations of builds.

[Developer site explanation for configuring build.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html)

Please, explain the difference between different configurations for builds. Plus kindly tell how can I make an app variant ??

I am currently working on a project in which I have 2 different modules.

- User Module
- Admin Module

I want to make variants in this case but I don't know how to ??

p.s What build configuration would you suggest for this basic user-admin project ??

Answer (score 0):

You can for example add following to your build.gradle (and set different package names for the different build flavors)

```
productFlavors {
    user {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.user"
    }
    admin {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.admin"
    }
```

You can also use this approach to set flavor specific string values....for example using something like

`resValue "string", "some_string_name", "flavor specific string value"`

Comment: Appreciated :) 
Could you please tell me the difference between each build configuration ??